# C# architecture for long-lived data collecting server apps

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-services

We are about to start a new project for a server application, for the purpose of collecting data from several data sources and storing it in a database.

For a quick test, we created a WinForms app which uses the core functionality from a custom library, and now have to start migrating it towards the final product.

From what we've done so far, the best way to do this should be to make it a Windows service and then expose basic monitoring and configuration to a thin Win or Web client through remoting/web services.

Is there a more appropriate way to make such an application?

Comment: Sounds right. You might want to build the application to support scaling and distribution if it will grow.

Comment: @bzlm: Thanks. Did you have something in particular in mind with "build the application to support scaling"? Choice of persistence layer? Map-reduce processing? We *should* encapsulate layers properly, so that such changes are available when time comes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider exposing the service itself using the WCF/ADO.NET Data Services: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792.aspx

Also see this for a quick walkthrough on how to expose a WCF Data Service: http://www.msteched.com/2010/NorthAmerica/DEV324

Comment: Thanks, but that's mostly related to data abstraction once it has been processed. I am actually more concerned about the format of the actual "data concentrator" app. I was wondering if Win Services are still the best way to do it.

Comment: Well, if you need a web interface, perhaps you could consider hosting it in IIS (and use ASP.NET MVC or similar).